# IntelliJ 10.5: how to NOT add "test" scoped dependencies in generated .apk file?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, apk

I've added several dependencies in my Android project in IntelliJ, for unit-tests (`JUnit4`, `JMock`, `SQLite-jdbc`, etc.). I defined all of them as "test" scope in the module dependencies settings, so that they are used only when running my unt-tests and they don't get in the way of the production code.

My problem is that when the .apk file is generated, it basically ignores the "test" scope setting, and includes all the unneeded dependencies, which boost the size of the .apk by a dozen MBs.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android tests can run on device, therefore test dependencies may be required to actually run them. If classes that you are using in the tests are already available on the device as a part of Android platform, you can try setting the scope to **Provided**.

Comment: I'm talking of the basic unit-tests for my business logic, which I don't run on the device or emulator, I run them through a normal JVM not using the android SDK, so I'm sure they are never needed on the .apk (I have another set of tests for the UI, using Robotium) - I didn't know there was a "Provided" scope, will check it out, it sounds like it may solve my problem, thanks

Comment: You can also try to make a separate Java module in IDEA for your tests that don't have to run on device.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to avoid that, and wanted to know if there was another way before doing that. I don't like having multiple modules, I prefer to keep everything in a common one - will test the "provided" scope first

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like Provided doesn't change anything. Jars are still in the apk...

Comment: SO I finally created a new module for my unit-tests, thanks for your help

Comment: Can't reproduce, in my project jars with Provided scope are not packaged into APK. Try IDEA 11: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11+EAP or contact JetBrains support with a sample project to reproduce this problem.